# Use T-SQL to Generate hash on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql, hash, password-recovery

I have a MYSQL database that one of my fellow staff members left on the internet, He died in a car accident last week, and now I am stuck trying to get the hash from the database. The shh to the computer is the same as password, so once I recover the mysql I recover the server.
I need to get his password, and I have access to the mysql - user table. So I know what the password is, kinda 
The hash`s are

```
53F729269405F0E0706778FE9567FEAFD9C3B2AD
```

and

```
FA14C37196BAFC3E0E2819E281819A1B7C83CDA3
```

I have no console access to the server, and I have no hope of getting it.

I was thinking that if I brute force it with t-sql on the lines of getting the mysql to generate sequential hashes and match them against the existing. Kinda like this idea

```
SELECT SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1("password")));
```

returns 2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19
Would it be better to write a c# script to do this or use t-sql?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you can connect to the DB you can update that HASH. No need to brute force it just update it to a know hash, like your password hash.  also if you can edit the system/app you can by pass the password validation

Comment: I need access to the ssh , that is the same password as the mysql.